# including parameter values in save.image (R)

Tags: r, filenames

I am interested in knowing how to include the value of a parameter in the filename when saving the workspace in R. I use matlab, and i am looking for something similar to this in R:

```
save(['database_' num2str(parametervalue) '_' num2str(parameter2value) '.mat'])
```

Thus, is it possible to save different workspaces without changing the name by hand?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at `paste` and `paste0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
save.image(paste('database_', as.character(parametervalue), '_', as.character(parameter2value), '.mat', sep = ""))
```

Hope it helps.